# Cocos2d-x Subclassing Issue CCMenuItemImage

Tags: c++, subclass, cocos2d-x, ccmenuitem

I'm trying to create a button that is derived from the base class CCMenuItemImage. I want this button to be able to call it's function when it's first touched instead of after the touch ends. However, trying to subclass, I get an error saying it's an invald conversion.

button.ccp:

```
#include "button.h"

void Button::selected(){
CCLOG("SELECTED");
}

void Button::unselected(){
CCLOG("UNSELECTED");
}

Button* Button::create(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage, const char     *disabledImage, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector) {
Button *button = new Button();
    if (button && button->initWithNormalImage(normalImage, selectedImage,     disabledImage, NULL, NULL))
    {
        button->autorelease();
        return button;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(button);
    return NULL;

}
```

button.h:

```
#ifndef BUTTON_H
#define BUTTON_H
#include "cocos2d.h"

class Button : public cocos2d::CCMenuItemImage{
public:
virtual void selected();

virtual void unselected();

};

#endif
```

SinglePlayer.ccp piece:

```
Button *left1 = Button::create("turncircle.png","turncircle.png", this, menu_selector(SinglePlayer::turning));
```

Comment: did you define this create() function in .h file ? if not, you should put `Button* Button::create(const char *normalImage, const char *selectedImage, const char     *disabledImage, CCObject* target, SEL_MenuHandler selector);` there.

Comment: @m.ding It says 'SEL_MenuHandler' has not been declared.

Comment: did you put `using namespace cocos2d;` in your h file?

Comment: After adding it, the remaining error is 
extra qualification 'Button::' on member 'create'

Comment: Sorry it's my fault, you should remove the `Button::` in h file

Comment: @m.ding cannot call member function 'Button* Button::create(char const*, char const*, char const*, cocos2d::CCObject*, cocos2d::SEL_MenuHandler)' without 
 object. How do I go about this?

Comment: make it static. in h file. `static Button*...`

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `/CCMenu.cpp', needed by CCMenu.o'.

Comment: delete everything in the proj.android/libs and proj.android/objs. But I do think you need to read some books about c++ and ndk before you jumping straight in to cocos2d-x.

Comment: I would still like to get this problem figured out if you're still out there. I deleted the folders and it still didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Looks like a file was deleted so all is working now. I have one final question. I'm using selected() to run the activate() method. However, once I end the touch, it runs activates() again. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: overwrite the CCTouchEnded

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I added the ccTouchBegan and ccTouchEnded methods and their virtual prototypes, but it still doesn't behave like I want.

Comment: are they virtual in CCMenuItemImage? if not, you cannot overwrite them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MenuItem select() is triggered on touch finished by default.

You need to subclass CCSprite with Touch registered with dispatcher and overwrite the ccTouchBegan

Answer (score 1):

What I can understand is that you are trying to do manual control with the touches of your CCMenuItemImage. Actually all the touches are being handled in CCMenu not in MenuItem so you have to inherit CCMenu rather CCMenuItemImage to override the touches.

In my game I had this problem with CCTableView and CCMenuItem where MenuItem was a prioritised in taking gestures. So I tweaked it with inheriting CCMenu.

It also contain some extra code but just to make everything gets intact I am pasting everything.

> **ScrollMenu.h Class**

```
class ScrollMenu:public CCMenu
{
public:
ScrollMenu();
virtual ~ScrollMenu(){};

bool isMovedGesture_;
bool istabBar_;
CCMenuItem * previousSelectedItem_;
static ScrollMenu* create(CCMenuItem* item,...);
virtual void registerWithTouchDispatcher();

virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *touch, CCEvent* event);
CREATE_FUNC(ScrollMenu);
};

class ScrollMenuLoader : public cocos2d::extension::CCNodeLoader
{
public:
    CCB_STATIC_NEW_AUTORELEASE_OBJECT_METHOD(ScrollMenuLoader, loader);

protected:
    CCB_VIRTUAL_NEW_AUTORELEASE_CREATECCNODE_METHOD(ScrollMenu);
};
```

> **ScrollMenu.cpp Class**

```
#include "ScrollMenu.h"

ScrollMenu* ScrollMenu::create(CCMenuItem* item, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, item);
    ScrollMenu *pRet = new ScrollMenu();
    if (pRet && pRet->initWithItems(item,args))
    {
        pRet->autorelease();
        va_end(args);
        return pRet;
    }
    va_end(args);
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(pRet);
    return NULL;
}
ScrollMenu::ScrollMenu()
{
    isMovedGesture_ = false;
}

void ScrollMenu::registerWithTouchDispatcher()
{
    CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    pDirector->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, false);
}

bool ScrollMenu::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{
    return CCMenu::ccTouchBegan(touch, event);
}

void ScrollMenu::ccTouchMoved(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{
    CC_UNUSED_PARAM(event);
    CCAssert(m_eState == kCCMenuStateTrackingTouch, "[Menu ccTouchMoved] -- invalid state");
    isMovedGesture_ = true;
}

void ScrollMenu::ccTouchEnded(CCTouch *touch, CCEvent* event)
{
    CC_UNUSED_PARAM(touch);
    CC_UNUSED_PARAM(event);
    CCAssert(m_eState == kCCMenuStateTrackingTouch, "[Menu ccTouchEnded] -- invalid state");

    CCMenuItem * currentItem = this->itemForTouch(touch);
    if(!currentItem && isMovedGesture_ && m_pSelectedItem)
    {

        if(!istabBar_ || (previousSelectedItem_ && previousSelectedItem_ != m_pSelectedItem))
        {
            m_pSelectedItem->unselected();
        }
    }
    else if(currentItem)
    {
        if(currentItem == m_pSelectedItem)
        {
            if(!isMovedGesture_)
            {
                m_pSelectedItem->activate();
                previousSelectedItem_ = m_pSelectedItem;
            }
            else{
                if(previousSelectedItem_ != m_pSelectedItem)
                {
                    m_pSelectedItem->unselected();
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if(isMovedGesture_)
            {
                m_pSelectedItem->unselected();
                m_pSelectedItem = currentItem;
                m_pSelectedItem->activate();
                previousSelectedItem_ = m_pSelectedItem;
            }

        }
        if (!istabBar_) {
            currentItem->unselected();
        }
    }

    m_eState = kCCMenuStateWaiting;
    isMovedGesture_ = false;

}
```

Comment: Any idea how this is done using cocos2d-x version 3.x ?